# How to manipulate Object through the selectedItem of a Combobox

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

Just in case someone want to help me, i will appreciate a lot that, because i'm noob in java and trying to learn simply concept and, in the same time, to maintain code clean and simply to read. If you think that it's a stupid question because i have the wrong approach with coding, i will really care about your opinion and if you explain me why i will try to get your experience.

Now the questions is:

I have a mainApp containing observableList of persons and observableList of events

```
public class MainApp extends Application {
   private Stage primaryStage;
   private BorderPane rootLayout;
   private ObservableList<Evento> eventi = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
   private ObservableList<Person> persons = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

   public ObservableList<Evento> getEventi() {
       return eventi;
   }

   public ObservableList<Person> getPersons() {
       return persons;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}

   public void start(Stage primaryStage){
       this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
       this.primaryStage.setTitle("Bettator Events"); 

       Person test = new Person("Daniele", "Giaquinto");
       test.getEventi().add(new Evento("danEvento", 1.0, "testConto"));
       persons.add(test);
       Person test2 = new Person("Roberto", "Sellitto");
       test2.getEventi().add(new Evento("robEvento", 31.0, "testCo"));
       persons.add(test2);

       initRootLayout();
       showEventiLayout();
}
```

Person object have a list of events too, i created it after, because i was trying to create a responsive GUI, so in this case, instead of one list of events, every single person have their events list.

```
public class Person {
   private StringProperty firstName;
   private StringProperty lastName;
   private StringProperty nickName;
   private ObservableList<Evento> eventi = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

i created into the EventyLayout a comboBox and a tableView, when i change the combobox, using a listener, the tableView will be populated with the events list of that person object, i did that filling the mainApp events list with the Selected Person Events List

(EventiController)

```
public class EventiLayoutController {
private MainApp mainApp;

@FXML
private ComboBox<Person> utenteCmb;
@FXML
private TableView<Evento> eventiTbl;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Evento, String> eventoCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Evento, Double> importoCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Evento, String> contoCol;

@FXML
void initialize() {

    eventoCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nomeProperty());
    importoCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().importoProperty().asObject());
    contoCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().contoProperty());
    utenteCmb.setCellFactory((comboBox) -> new ListCell<Person>() {
        //cut for stackoverflow
    });
    utenteCmb.setConverter(new StringConverter<Person>() {
        //cut for stackoverflow
    });
    utenteCmb.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        mainApp.getEventi().clear();
        mainApp.getEventi().addAll(newValue.getEventi());
    });
}

public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp){
    this.mainApp = mainApp;

    eventiTbl.setItems(mainApp.getEventi());
    utenteCmb.setItems(mainApp.getPersons());
}
```

}

Before the project was without the possibility to switch user, and i created an "handleAddEvent" to add event into the mainApp list, in the rootLayoutController (the one that show me the menuBar and menu item, where Add button is)

```
public class RootLayoutController {

private MainApp mainApp;

@FXML // ResourceBundle that was given to the FXMLLoader
private ResourceBundle resources;

@FXML // URL location of the FXML file that was given to the FXMLLoader
private URL location;

@FXML // This method is called by the FXMLLoader when initialization is complete
void initialize() {

}

/**
 * Needed for pass the MainApp to this controller ad use the public variable
 */
public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp){
    this.mainApp = mainApp;
}

/**
 * Open dialog for add a new event, then add it to the event collection
 */
@FXML
private void handleAdd() {
    Evento evento = new Evento();
    boolean okClicked = mainApp.showEventiEditEditDialog(evento);
    if (okClicked)
        mainApp.getEventi().add(evento);
}
}
```

but then i tried to go more deep into learning, and i need to add that event directly into the person->event, if i try to add it using the same function, he will add it to the mainApp events list and not to the person events List, even if the mainApp persons list is filled with the person events.

I was wondering if there is a way to pass as pointer the observableList to the mainApp or there is a simple-way to reach my objective.

RootLayoutController didn't know that there is a combobox when he try to add the event, and mainApp too, didn't have to know that there is a combobox, so how to get the selectedPerson and add an event to his events list?

Should i create a "activePerson" into the mainApp and switch it everytime the user change item into the combobox? But it seem to me and "hard coding" method.

How you will do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is no one right way of designing the app. Of course there are some design principles, which you should try to follow. There are a lot of information about the topic, so won't be a problem to find it.
About your specific case, I would move combobox and `Person` selection logic from `EventiLayoutController` to `RootLayoutController`. This way you would have selected `Person` instance in root controller and can notify event controller when change occurred and provide selected `Person` to it. Notify can be done either by having `EventiLayoutController` instance directly in `RootLayoutController` or using event bus approach for example.
Also instead of `mainApp.getEventi().addAll(newValue.getEventi());` I'd use property binding (or bidirectional binding, depending on your logic). But really I don't quite understand why you need separate `eventi` collection in MainApp, if you are filling it with selected person events anyway.